# parallel: Warning: No more file handles

Tags: gnu-parallel, ulimit

I am running GNU parallel and after some time I am getting:

```
parallel: Warning: no more file handles Raising ulimit -n or etc/security/limits.conf may help.
```

What argument would be appropriate to add to the parallel command in order to overcome this?

I changed `limits.conf` to `unlimited` but then I could not use `sudo` or login as `root` or `ssh` to my box same issue like [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/836929/can-not-login-after-change-limits-conf)

here is the piece of code that I am using. I have 2 files, one with passwords second with hosts.

```
passPasswords_and_hosts() {
        `sudo sshpass -p "$1" ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2 root@"$2" -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$command_linux"`
}
export -f testone
export -p command_linux
parallel --tag -k passPasswords_and_hosts :::: "$passwords" "$linux_hosts"
```

Comment: I think we need to see the command you are running and a small example that can be reproduced.

Comment: Can you post output of `ulimit -a`?

Comment: @OleTange  core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 256634
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited

Comment: @OleTange and the rest:
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

Comment: 'open files (-n) 1024' You need to increase this - just like the warning says. Each parallel job takes 4 file handles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid having tmp files laying around after abnormal termination (think `kill -9` or system crash), GNU Parallel opens tmp files and removes them immediately. But it keeps the files open.

To meet the requirement of `--keep-order` it has to keep all the files open that have not been printed yet. So if you have 1000000 commands and command 2 is stuck forever, then GNU Parallel will happily run command 3 and beyond, but if command 2 does not come unstuck, then GNU Parallel will eventually run out of file handles (it uses 4 file handles per job).

In your case your `passPasswords_and_hosts` probably becomes stuck at some point. In your output it would be the job following the last output (i.e. the job not yet printed).

So try running that job by hand and see if there is some obvious problem.

You can also remove `-k`. Then your stuck job will still use 4 file handles, but all the following jobs that completes, will not, as they will be printed when they are done.

Finally you can use `--timeout`. I normally use `--timeout 1000%`. This means that if a job takes longer than 10x the *median* run time of all successful jobs, then it is killed. It works for a remarkable range of situations.

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful, I tested the IP where my job is getting stuck. So nmap mistakenly recognized OS as Linux while it was windows. It was corrected once I used "nmap -F -O " instead of "nmap  -O -p 22". So when I sshpass to it I get: "searching for password prompt using match "assword" SSHPASS read: Username" I also tried to just ssh to it and I cannot log in to it as root (because it's not a Linux machine) I am looking for a way to move on to next ip and kill this process if something like that happens

Comment: so I just tested --timeout and it works like a charm.
from GNU Parallel documentation: If jobs taking more than a certain amount of time are known to fail, they can be stopped with --timeout. The accuracy of --timeout is 2 seconds:

  parallel --timeout 4.1 sleep {}\; echo {} ::: 2 4 6 8
Output:

  2
  4
GNU parallel can compute the median runtime for jobs and kill those that take more than 200% of the median runtime:

  parallel --timeout 200% sleep {}\; echo {} ::: 2.1 2.2 3 7 2.3
Output:

  2.1
  2.2
  3